# Access all projects (teams) in Asana - admin read

Tags: asana, asana-api

I have an app that I want to be able to access all teams and their projects. Is there an admin user, or a way to authenticate as an admin. Rather than having to use a specific user that needs to be added to each team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Asana does have an admin role called a [Service Account](https://asana.com/guide/help/premium/service-accounts), however, this is an [Enterprise feature](https://asana.com/guide/team/advanced/enterprise-overview).

With Service Accounts, administrators have complete access to all of the data in Asana via the API.